# How to emulate 'cp -a' on Solaris which does not have it?

Tags: solaris, cp

How to do a `cp -a` on a Solaris system which does not support the `-a` option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cp -pPR
```

If yours have them. Thats the same as the `-a` flag.

Answer (score 2):

`cp -a` is not quite equivalent to `cp -pPR`.  In particular, at least in newer versions of Solaris, `-a` implies `--preserve=all`, while `-p` only preserves `mode,ownership,timestamps`.  (`--preserve=all` also preserves additional attributes such as `context,links,xattr`).

From a newer release of Solaris' man page:

```
   -a, --archive
          same as -dR --preserve=all
```